# best practices to compress/encrypt

Tags: c#, encryption, compression

My problem is related on how store massive informations on a 3D terrain. These informations should be secret and since they are very bulky should also be compressed.
I opted for file storage and now I was wondering to know the best pracitces to encrypt/compress (or compress/encrypt) object data to files.

I just don't even know if it would be better to write to file and then compress and encrypt it or if work on a data stream and then write to file.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just don't even know if it would be better to write to file and then compress and encrypt it or if work on a data stream and then write to file.

"Better" is not measurable. In-memory compression and encryption may be faster than directly writing to file, but can easily prove troublesome if the data is larger than what fits in memory.

As you do want the end result stored on disk, I'd approach it like this (first compress, then encrypt, then write to disk):

```
using (var compressionStream = new CompressionStream(rawData))
{
    using (var encryptionStream = new EncryptionStream(compressionStream))
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("outputfile"))
        {
            encryptionStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

The implementations of `CompressionStream` and  `EncryptionStream` of course depend on the APIs you use.

Comment: Just want to add, that you cannot (practically) compress already encrypted file. Because after encryption, the content must be pseudo-random (otherwise the encryption is really poor). And you cannot compress random sequence, because there is no repetitions and no patterns - that's the whole point of encryption. So if you want to shrink your data, make sure to compress it first and then encrypt.

Comment: Thank you for this explaination.
If I would like to be enrouted to a particular API, what would you suggets, considering that my priority is security and then minimizing the data size?

Comment: If your priority is security, use an encryption API. When it is minimizing the data size, use a compression API. The specific implementation heavily relies on your intended usage and data characteristics, but you can always take a look at .NET's [`GzipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

Comment: great! so a fine approach could be to write some adapter `GzipStream` And `CryptoStream` for example?

Comment: @Leggy that's fine. See the MSDN pages of those classes for some examples; it's fairly easy to combine them.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I found that zlib.net (using ComponentAce.Compression.Libs.zlib) is a thousand times better than the inbuilt compression in VS.

Answer (score 4):

Compression and encryption are interesting beasts - the act of encryption randomises the bits, which then makes GZip compression more difficult.

See the notes in this file. https://serverfault.com/questions/17855/can-i-compress-an-encrypted-file

Doing as CodeCaster says in that order will produce the smallest file, as the file is already compressed before encyrption.

Also consider file size and the types of disks that store it, along with the types of machines that decrypt and uncompress. If you are streaming it back into memory, you may find you run out of memory in certain situations, unless you take the stream up into buffers, or break the files up.

Comment: this sounds interesting as long as I could understand in depth the meaning of your last statement. what's the relevance of the machine used to compress/decompress?

Comment: If you have a machine with a small amount of RAM available compared to the size of the object there is a real risk that you will end up with an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: You also should consider the profile of the Disk used to store the data if possible. There is optimisations that you can do if you know the media - you may choose to do parallel streams of smaller data if you are not bound by IO (say if you have a SSD or certain RAID array), or you may choose a different strategy (large contiguous pieces) if your system prefers to serialise and encrypt. There is some trial and  error here. Of course, if you don't control the disk, then you might need to generalise. I wouldn't make the files too large though - its generally easier to manage.